Large contour not found in binary image
I have a binary image (binary_image_full_sizes.png) and I would like to find the large oval contour in the middle. The cv2.findContours() function does not return the contour I’m looking for but when I scale the image by 1/2, it finds the contour. How can I make it find the contour for the full size image?
 inverted_binary_image = cv2.imread('binary_image_full_scale.png')

    white_pixels = np.sum(inverted_binary_image == 255)

    # # Find Canny edges 
    edged = cv2.Canny(inverted_binary_image, 30, 200) 
    
    # Finding Contours 
    # Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy() 
    # since findContours alters the image 
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 

    min_area = white_pixels / 10

    filtered_contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > min_area]

    # Convert inverted_binary_image to a color image
    inverted_binary_image = cv2.cvtColor(inverted_binary_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    cv2.drawContours(inverted_binary_image, filtered_contours, 0, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    # Save the image with drawn contours
    contour_image_path = 'binary_image_with_countours_half_scaled.png'
    cv2.imwrite(contour_image_path, inverted_binary_image)

Image 1:

Image 2:


Why are you using Canny?  You can get the contours from the thresholded input and the largest contour.

What's the difference between the two images you linked? If you invert the image (the oval being white) then cv2.findContours() should extract it. Don't apply edge detection though.

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/large-contour-not-found-in-binary-image/18955

There was a very similar post not so long ago about avocado detection on staging ground, it has been deleted. Just use cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats or get the largest contour with largestContour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea).  I hope this helps you further. Consider answering and closing your own questions based on the helpful comments. P.S. you really do not need Canny.

Invert your image so the oval is white on black background. Then threshold, then get contours and then find the largest with largestContour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea) as mentioned above.

That whole code example is sketchy, inverted_binary_image is BGR since imread was run with default flags. Of course cv2.Canny is pointless here, and so would be running findContours with cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL on the original image, given that the background is white. There ought to be some canonicals for all of those things, but I honestly don't know where right now.

The trick is to realize that cv2.findContours() method expects blobs to be white on the binary image, as others already pointed out.
A simple color inversion can solve that problem and then all you need to do is to figure out what is the largest contour.
A working example can be found here which displays the largest contour in green:

Reference source code:
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load input image
bgr_image = cv2.imread('xVFenHPi.png')

# Convert the input image to grayscale
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Invert colors so white blobs can be identified as contours
gray_image = cv2.bitwise_not(gray_image)

# Extract all contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray_image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 

# Draw all contours found in red
all_contours_img = bgr_image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(all_contours_img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 4)

# print and draw the largest contour found
largest_contour_img = bgr_image.copy()

if len(contours) == 0:
    print("!!! No contours found")
    exit(0)

# Find the largest contour by the area
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

# Draw the biggest contour in green
cv2.rectangle(largest_contour_img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 4)

# Display the original and processed images
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.imshow(gray_image, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.title('All contours')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(all_contours_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.title('Largest contour')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(largest_contour_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Out of curiosity, does the following statement hold for all retrievel modes? "The trick is to realize that cv2.findContours() method expects blobs to be white on the binary image, as others already pointed out."

There is some old documentation from OpenCV 3 that clearly states that they must be white but this paragraph changed or was removed in OpenCV 4.
